# Sequential animation in jquery

Tags: jquery, fade, sequential, jquery-callback

[a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xXbbX/2/)

When I click a colored box at the top of the screen, I want to fade out the boxes and watermark, then fade them back in, but I don't want the animations to overlap.

The problem I'm having is that the watermark (large grey text) sometimes fades in and out several times, and that the animations take place in the wrong order. I've found some other posts about similar problems, but they all assume the elements to be animated are called #item1, #item2, etc, and use a loop.

Edit: What I ended up doing was

```
function transition(text,title)
{
    $('.boxes').animate({opacity:0},400,"linear",function() {
        $('.watermark').animate({opacity:0},400,"linear",function(){
            $('.watermark').html(text);
            $('.watermark').animate({opacity:1},400,"linear",function(){
                $('.' + title).animate({opacity:1},400,"linear");
            });
        });
    });
}
```

I'm not sure why these callbacks work when the fade* ones didn't.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if I understood exactly what you were looking for. I've updated your example to use the `jQuery.when()` method - http://jsfiddle.net/jaredhoyt/xXbbX/8/

Please let me know if that is not the desired effect.

As a side note, I would strongly recommend using the [1TBS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style#Variant%3a_1TBS) indent style over the [Allman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style#Allman_style) style in JavaScript. Though it's a matter of preference in most languages, it actually has dangerous implications in JavaScript.

Comment: This is pretty much what I'm looking for, but I'd like the boxes to disappear before/appear after the watermark.

Also, I'm gonna read about 1tbs. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The effect of fading in and fading out, is because the previous animation was never stopped. I just added stops in front of each of your animations, to ensure that they've stopped, before processing their own animation.

```
function transition(text,title)
{
    $('.boxes').stop().fadeOut(400,function()
    {
        $('.watermark').stop().fadeOut(400,function()
        {
            $('.watermark').html(text);
            $('.watermark').stop().fadeIn(400,function()
            {
                $('.'+title).stop().fadeIn(400);
            });
        });
    });
}



$(document).ready(function()
{

    $('li span').click(function()
    {
        var text = $(this).html();
        var title = $(this).attr('title');
        if(text == 'Show All')
        {
            text = "watermark";
        }

        transition(text,title);
    });
});
​
```

Comment: If I remove the .stop() from the watermark fadein, the elements appear in the right order, but are still disappearing at the same time.

I guess I'm confused about callback functions. Aren't they supposed to only execute after the parent function finishes?

Comment: Wait a second, you're wanting each of the .boxes to fade out one by one?

Comment: I want all the elements with .boxes to fade out at once, and once they're gone, then fade the .watermark